# Use Trigger Ready Flow /Process Builder to add Members to Case Team

Tags: visual-workflow, flow, process-builder, case-teams

I would like to use Trigger Ready Flows -  whenever Status updates from A to B on a case, The Case Owner will be auto-added as a Member on the Case Team. I know that this is possible with a trigger but I would like to use point /click customisation if possible. Any ideas on how this could be completed with Flow /Process Builder?

Comment: What have you tried so far? There is no reason why you couldn't have a flow create a case team member on a case.  And fire that flow from a Process Builder that is triggered when the status changes from A to B.

Comment: Yes you can create a case team member, I just looked at my Flow sObjects and caseTeamMember is there, http://screencast.com/t/qZVPDDhN.  Unsure if Process builder can get to it, but I don't see why not since it's built on top of Flow.  Either way you can call a flow from the Process Builder.

Comment: Fifedog or Clehan1, could you detail the solution you used to make this happen. I have been trying to add the case creator to case team with no avail... Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just going to repeat my comment since I believe this does answer your question.  I just looked at my Flow sObjects and caseTeamMember is there, [screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/qZVPDDhN).  You should have no troubles building what you need with Process Builder and/or Flow.

Comment: I can see with the Flow that it is possible to create the case team, but is there a way that I can pass parameters (RoleID, ParentID) using the Process Builder? This would be possible with using a custom button but I cannot see how to do so with Process Builder?

Comment: I think you'll need to use Flows and a Flow trigger.  The Flow will hold your logic of creation of the related case team.  Your Flow trigger will pass in those parameters.  Set up a new workflow rule and then for your action select flow trigger.  From there it will ask about what parameters to pass in.

Comment: Unfortunately, Flow Triggers are no longer in Dev orgs. I believe Salesforce are fading them out to focus on using just Process Builder.

Comment: Hum... I do see that now I'm in my dev org... that's odd.  let me try and dig a little, hope to get back to you later today.

Comment: OK after a bit of digging you're right it does seem Salesforce is going towards PB instead of flow triggers.  That said here is a screen shot of my PB when I've selected a flow: [link](http://screencast.com/t/e6PujR6j)

This should give you what you need?

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I am not getting any option to pass variables. I am just getting the option to select (launch) a Flow. No other options become available.

Comment: Please disregard above comment - I have had no variables created for the Flow so it was not giving me the option.

Comment: Also be sure to set the variable to Input.  If you don't it will not show in the list.